# Silence NewRelic Logging to Console

Tags: ios, newrelic

I've added the New Relic iOS SDK to my project, and it's logging all kinds of information I'm not interested in to the console. I was hoping to find a way to disable it, and found the "Changing the Logging Level" section of [this page](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-apps/ios-installation-and-configuration#configuration), but the code provided didn't work.

I've tried the both of the following to no avail before the startWithApplicationToken: call

```
[NRLogger setLogLevels:NRLogLevelNone];
[NRLogger setLogTargets:NRLogTargetNone];
```

Is there some other option I need to set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In New Relic for iOS 3.174, which was released on January 8, we removed some logging messages that did not pay attention to the log level and target selection. If you're using an older version of the SDK please grab the latest version here: https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/releases/ios

Comment: I am using latest version 5.14.2 in my swift project and i have set NRLogger.setLogLevels(NRLogLevelNone.rawValue). Still it prints all the logs. Any idea?